# Slipping into a target in Boxing vs Real Life Defense

Tags: technique, self-defense, boxing, muay-thai

For Boxing and Muay Thai, Slipping requires an athlete to go shoulder to knee, or move forward diagonal left, or forward-diagonal right.

In real-life defense situations, is this a good strategy? Moving into a tactic seems risky and dangerous in real life, with one knockout punches where opponent does not have cushioned gloves or possibly holding a knife/weapon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will try to answer that question as objectively as I can, but obviously, it is highly situational.

1. Going into an infight without seeing both hands is always problematic due to hidden weapons.
2. Given you can rule out that the opponent does hold or is able to draw a weapon in time, there is nothing in principle which speaks against covering distance. A good slip brings you into a zone where effective striking is difficult for them.
3. You should only do this when you know what you are doing this for, ie. if you can control the situation from there on. Mainly in order not to allow the use of hidden weapons and end the fight ASAP.

For example, I myself am a grappler mainly. Thus, if I get the opportunity, I would always go in and compromise the opponent's structure so that I can control their movements. If my background was boxing, it would depend on whether I felt comfortable in infight situations and knew how to land hits without hurting myself. If it was Karate, I'd not even consider it, for Muay Thai I'd certainly feel much more comfortable as I can use knees and elbows and control the opponent in clinch.

In short: The key to the decision is a good assessment of the situation and your own abilities. If you know what to do and have trained for that, the risk is pretty low. If you never trained for tactical assessment or fighting without gloves, this is not the time to start with it.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have entered a situation where you can slip a strike, you are already in a risky and dangerous situation. Defending strikes is not trivial; remaining stationary is not clearly safer than moving the target, which is usually your face. My personal preference would be to move outside to prevent the expected second strike from landing; I have more confidence adding movement to defense than hands alone.

At this close range, I'm not sure you have a choice about engagement, regardless of whether the attacker has a weapon.

Answer (score 0):

There's pros and cons of each defense which is why you want all of them in your toolbox "just in case".

Both your examples suggest things where you probably don't want to get hit if you can avoid it.